# testdriven.io: Error when requiring Flask app context within Celery task

Tags: python, flask, celery

My project is similar to:
https://testdriven.io/courses/flask-celery/app-factory/

(Flask application built with application factory and Celery instance configured by celery_utils.py like shown in the course.

However, in my project, I need a task to use the config values from the Flask app.

In my Flask blueprint, I have a route which looks like this:

```
@admin_blueprint.route("/send_notification", methods=["GET"])
def send_notification():
    tasks_telegram.send_telegram_notification.apply_async(
                args=["This is a test message"])
```

Where the task_telegram.py file looks like this:

```
from celery import shared_task
from flask import current_app

from ..core import telegram

@shared_task
def send_telegram_notification(message: str):
    app = current_app
    telegram_bot_key = app.config.get("TELEGRAM_BOT_KEY", "")
    telegram_chat_id = app.config.get("TELEGRAM_CHAT_ID", "")
    telegram_obj = telegram.Telegram(bot_key=telegram_bot_key, chat_id=telegram_chat_id)
    telegram_obj.send_telegram_notification(message=message)
```

I get an error triggered by:

```
in send_telegram_notification
    telegram_bot_key = app.config.get("TELEGRAM_BOT_KEY", "")
```

With the following error message:

```
[2023-08-06 22:59:07,648: ERROR/MainProcess] Task app.tasks.tasks_telegram.send_telegram_notification[efd2ca52-6d0c-433b-8c9b-104255ae3f46] raised unexpected: RuntimeError('Working outside of application context.\n\nThis typically means that you attempted to use functionality that needed\nthe current application. To solve this, set up an application context\nwith app.app_context(). See the documentation for more information.')
...
RuntimeError: Working outside of application context.

This typically means that you attempted to use functionality that needed
the current application. To solve this, set up an application context
with app.app_context(). See the documentation for more information.
```

Any suggestion on how to call app.config.get("TELEGRAM_BOT_KEY", "") from within the task ?

I tried to rewrite the task file as follows:

```
from celery import shared_task
from flask import current_app


from ..core import telegram


@shared_task
def send_telegram_notification(message: str):
    with app.app_context():
        app = current_app
        telegram_bot_key = app.config.get("TELEGRAM_BOT_KEY", "")
        telegram_chat_id = app.config.get("TELEGRAM_CHAT_ID", "")
        telegram_obj = telegram.Telegram(
            bot_key=telegram_bot_key, chat_id=telegram_chat_id
        )
        telegram_obj.send_telegram_notification(message=message)
```

But get the following error:

```
 line 10, in send_telegram_notification
    with app.app_context():
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'app' referenced before assignment
```

Answer (score 0):

current_app is a Proxy to the Flask() instance. While serving your request flask resolves this down to your app instance and use configuration values from there.

If you want to use those configuration values inside your celery, you have to import the flask app instance and push its context. You can either

1. Have a common configuration place and update celery and flask configurations separately to not deal with circular imports.

`OR`

2. You have to import flask app instance inside function, (which runs flask initialisation every time and is inefficient) and then use contextmanager like:

```
@shared_task
def send_telegram_notification(message: str):
    from flask_app import create_app
    app = create_app()
    with app.app_context():
        ...
```

Comment: thank you ! do you have a link to a reference web page on solution 1 ?